# login via github on appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, cookies, github

I want to implement login/signup via github, for a python application that i plan to build on **appengine**. I have went through the docs, it is easy to authenticate the user and based upon the callback response, login/signup the user. There are couple of libraries for python http://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/ that help doing it. I am *totally new to implementing login/signup on my own*. Just one question, do I need to take care of sessions and/or cookies as well. Meaning, a user logs in, closes the browser and then reopens, probably then he should be logged, my app should not ask him to log him in twice?

Is this taken care of, or do I need to write some middleware? 
If yes, could you please outline the steps or point to a resource/documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, accessing the Github API is basically sending HTTP requests and receiving responses, and Google App Engine allows the standard python functions to do so
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.

So I think current github libraries could work on GAE, unmodified or with very small 
modifications. The only things that don't work are PATCH requests (not supported on GAE), but they don't matter in your case anyways.

Comment: @whatf Just implement those things the way you would do with your own authentication system.
Btw, What framework are you using? Webapp2? Flask? Django?

Comment: I have not implemented those(secure authentication in sessions etc.) things. I am using webapp2.

Comment: Just read the docs, I also work with webapp2 and cookie/session is quite easy.

Comment: let me check and come back to you!